# How to find Min & Max from .text file

Tags: c, text, average

I have been working on this program that takes the name of people and scores that they would get on quizes, and put out the average, min and max. So far I can have the program read the file, and find the average, however it is only finding it for the last name and scores. I was wondering if anyone could help me with at least figuring out how to get the program to read all of the numbers rather than the last line, and if possible how to find the min and max per column in the text file... Thanks a ton for your help! Im completely lost here. :( here is my code so far thanks again!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
FILE *file;
char text[1000];
char fName[20];
char lName[20];
char *token;
int q1, q2, q3, q4, mid, mid2, final, finalgrade;
double ave, num = 0, min = 0, max = 0;


file=fopen("Input.txt","r");
while (fgets(text, sizeof(text), file) != NULL)
{
    token = strtok(text, " ");
    strcpy(fName, token);
    token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    strcpy(lName, token);
    token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    q1 = atoi(token);
    token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    q2 = atoi(token);
    token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    q3 = atoi(token);
    token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    q4 = atoi(token);
    token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    mid = atoi(token);
    token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    mid2 = atoi(token);
    token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    final = atoi(token);
    printf("%s %s, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n", fName, lName, q1, q2, q3, q4, mid, mid2, final);
}

ave=(q1+q2+q3+q4+mid+mid2+final)/7;
finalgrade=(q1*.10 + q2*.10 + q3*.10 + q4*.10 + mid*.20 + mid2*.20 + final*.25);

printf("\nHere are the class averages:\n");
printf("\t\t Q1\t Q2\t Q3\t Q4\t Mid1\t Mid2\t Final\n");
printf("Average:\t%.2lf\n", ave);
printf("Minimum:\t \n");
printf("Maximum:\t \n");
printf("\n");
fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: What is your input file format ? Do you have any issue in reading all the contents for text file ? Try with fscanf it may be suitable.

Comment: To find min&max get all the scores in array. Then sort the array. with  that you can find min&max

Comment: Your code is awful. Ident it and change the names. Use CamelCase name style and more self-explaining words.. then people will find it easier to read your code and help you.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you iterate through the while loop, you are overwriting all of your variables (`q1` through `q4`, `fName`, `lName`, etc.), but you aren't doing anything with them.  At the end of your loop, you still have the values from the last iteration, hence you are only doing the calculations for the last line.

If each person has all their data on one line, you can simply cut and paste these lines from after the while loop into the bottom of the while loop:

```
ave=(q1+q2+q3+q4+mid+mid2+final)/7;
finalgrade=(q1*.10 + q2*.10 + q3*.10 + q4*.10 + mid*.20 + mid2*.20 + final*.25);
printf("Average:\t%.2lf\n", ave);
```

If you want to get the minimun/maximum value for each column, you can have a variables such as `q1max` and `q1min`.  After reading the new value for `q1`, compare it to the minimum and maximum values for `q1` found so far, and fix them if needed.  You can do something like:

```
if (q1 > q1max)
    q1max = q1;
```

And something similar for `q1min`.  Just remember that before the while loop, you should set `q1min` to the *maximum* value someone could get for `q1`, and set `q1max` to the *minimum* value.  This is will allow these values to adjust to the minimum and maximum values for that column as you find them.  Then do the same thing for all your other variables.

Below is the code that should work for finding `q1`.  You'll have to copy and change the code for `q1` for the other tests as needed.  This won't do pretty column output - you'll have to do that yourself.  But hopefully this will illustrate the right approach.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
FILE *file;
char text[1000];
char fName[20];
char lName[20];
char *token;
int q1, q2, q3, q4, mid, mid2, final, finalgrade;

int q1max = 0, q1min = 100;
// Do the same for the others...

double ave, num = 0, min = 0, max = 0;


file=fopen("Input.txt","r");
while (fgets(text, sizeof(text), file) != NULL)
{
    token = strtok(text, " ");
    strcpy(fName, token);
    token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    strcpy(lName, token);
    token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    q1 = atoi(token);
    token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    q2 = atoi(token);
    token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    q3 = atoi(token);
    token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    q4 = atoi(token);
    token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    mid = atoi(token);
    token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    mid2 = atoi(token);
    token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    final = atoi(token);

    if (q1 > q1max)
        q1max = q1;
    if (q1 < q1min)
        q1min = q1;

    // Do the same for the others...

    printf("%s %s, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n", fName, lName, q1, q2, q3, q4, mid, mid2, final);

    ave=(q1+q2+q3+q4+mid+mid2+final)/7;
    finalgrade=(q1*.10 + q2*.10 + q3*.10 + q4*.10 + mid*.20 + mid2*.20 + final*.25);

    printf("Average:\t%.2lf\n", ave);
}

printf("Minimum for q1:\t %d\n", q1min);
printf("Maximum for q1:\t %d\n", q1max);

// Do the same for the others...

printf("\n");
fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: Also, you can save a line by doing `q1min = min(q1min, q1)`, or `q1min = q1 < q1min ? q1 : q1min` instead.

Comment: Thanks for all the help DiputsMonro! I was able to get most of it working but for the averages. I'm trying to have the averages be part of a table of sort. For example the average for all the Q1's should be 82.25, but for some reason i keep getting 87. I tried my code like this http://prntscr.com/4hdi10 but it simply kept repeating 87 in the table I made. I think it is because I am taking averages of the scores per line rather than per question if you get what I'm saying. Really appreciate the help as I am still trying to learn and your are definitely helping me understand.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this code.

```
int main()
{
    FILE* fp = fopen("Input.txt", "r");
    unsigned short _min = 0, _max = 0;
    char curLine[512];

    while(fgets(curLine, 512, fp))
    {
        sscanf(curLine, ",%i", &_min); // dont know how do you format the info
        printf("\nMinimum: %i\n", _min); // use same for max, apply the format.
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 1;
}
```

If you want to save all the data into a buffer use this function template instead:

```
int main()
{
    FILE* fp = fopen("Input.txt", "r");

    unsigned short _min[512] = {0}, _max[512] = {0};
    unsigned short i = 0;
    char curLine[512];

    while(fgets(curLine, 512, fp))
    {
        i++;
        sscanf(curLine, ",%i", &_min[i]); // dont know how do you format the info
        printf("\nMinimum: %i\n", _min[i]); // use same for max, apply the format.
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 1;
}
```

---

Clean function with dynamic allocation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* fp = fopen("loader.txt", "r");

    unsigned short *_min = malloc(1), *_max = malloc(1);
    unsigned short i = 0;
    char curLine[512];

    while(fgets(curLine, 512, fp))
    {
        int scanned = sscanf(curLine, ",%i", &_min[i]);
        printf("\nMinimum: %i\n", _min[i]); i++;
        realloc(_min, scanned);
    }

    fclose(fp); free(_min); free(_max); return 1;
}
```